# Name of a symmetry involving complex squares

Tags: complex-numbers, symmetry

Imagine a single parameter real-valued non-zero function $f$. For any complex number $Z$, let

$Z \rightarrow Z' = \Re(Z) f + i\Im(Z)/f $

Calculate $Z^2$ and $Z'^2$. Because the imaginary portion of the square is the product of the function f and its inverse, it is unchanged:

$\Im(Z^2) = \Im(Z'^2)$

Is there a name for this symmetry?

Comment: As written, $Z'$ is real.

Comment: Why does $f$ need to be a function ? It acts like a constant.

Comment: You actually don't specify what transformation your question is about. $Z\to Z'$ ? $W=Z^2\to Z'^2=W'$, which would mean $W'=(\Re\sqrt Wf+i\Im\sqrt W/f)^2$ ? or any transformation that preserves the imaginary part...

Comment: I am trying to ask the question in the most general way possible.  I want any transformation that when the complex number is squared, the imaginary part of that square is invariant. Certainly the function $f$ could be a constant function. If one wandered around a complex plane and $f$ varied, then the imaginary part of the square would be unchanged. The imaginary part of $Z'$ is $Im(Z)/f$.

Comment: I think you have forgotten an $i$ in your definition of $Z'$.  Do you mean a transformation like $x + i y \to x * f + i y / f$?

Comment: I was thinking about working on the complex manifold, $\mathbb{C}^1$. I could work with the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$. In that case, @AaronGolden is correct, I am interested in the transform: $Z = x + i y \rightarrow Z' = x * f + i y/f$. Square Z and Z' and the imaginary parts are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $Z'$ all belong to the same **[equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class)** as Z, if we define the equivalence relation as $z,z'\in\mathbb{C};\quad z\equiv z' \implies \Im(z^2)=\Im(z'^2)$.

We can prove this by proving $[z,z']$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Reflexive: $[z,z]\implies [z,z]$

Symmetric: $[z,z']\implies [z',z]$

Transitive: $[x,y] \land [y,z] \implies [x,z]$

all of which have trivial proofs.

Comment: I have not worked with equivalence classes before. My request for a "name for this symmetry" sounds incorrect since I was thinking about group theory. Unlike for groups, I suspect most equivalence classes don't get a particular name, but do get a precise equivalence relation.

Comment: there's modulo and conguent